# How can you filter invalid IP addresses to the PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table of IP addresses.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZrSM.png)

Through the Dropna () function I deleted Null elements.

I also removed repetitions and frequent addresses.

```
dt4new1 = dt4new.where("not (src = '0.0.0.0') and  not (dst = '0.0.0.0') ").where("not (src = '127.0.0.1') and  not (dst = '127.0.0.1') ").where("not (src = dst) ").where("not (src = '1')")
```

Now I have a table with pretty random names. How can I get rid of them?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85zNZ.png)

Comment: What is an *unwiting IP address*?

Comment: i'm sorry. I mean invalid.

Comment: Then [edit] your question title to correct it.

Comment: what names are you trying to get rid of? the column names?

Comment: No. In the second screenshot are shown in the column 'src'. For example: "1.3" " ," .194.32.185 " , ".32.187", "0.4" etc

Answer (score 1):

After all the removals for nulls and repetitions, you can flag the addresses that are valid, i.e. they have four set of numbers delimited by `.`.

Following is an example of flagging. The flag can be used to filter.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('ip_split', func.split('ip', '\.')). \
    withColumn('valid_flag', 
               func.size(func.expr('filter(ip_split, x -> x between 0 and 255)')) == 4
               ). \
    show()

# +-----------+----------------+----------+
# |         ip|        ip_split|valid_flag|
# +-----------+----------------+----------+
# |       1.3"|         [1, 3"]|     false|
# |.194.32.167|[, 194, 32, 167]|     false|
# | 0.77.160.4| [0, 77, 160, 4]|      true|
# +-----------+----------------+----------+
```

It splits the string by `.` and then only retains the elements that fall between 0 - 999. Taking a count of the retained elements can give you the flag - if there are 4 retained elements, the ip address is valid.

Comment: nice creative approach..shouldn't it be between 0 and 255 though?

Answer (score 0):

here's how i would write it. not sure what random names you are trying to get rid of based on the screenshot.

EDIT:
you can try using a regex function in a UDF to validate the ips

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import re

# Make a regular expression
# for validating an Ip-address
regex = "^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$"

def check_ip(ip): 
# pass the regular expression
# and the string in search() method
    if(re.search(regex, ip)):
        print("Valid Ip address")
        return True         
    else:
        print("Invalid Ip address")
        return False

check_ip_udf = F.udf(check_ip, BooleanType())

dt4new1 = dt4new.filter(
    ~F.col("src").isin("0.0.0.0", "127.0.0.1", "1")
    & ~F.col("dst").isin("0.0.0.0", "127.0.0.1")
    & (F.col("src") != F.col("dst"))
    & (check_ip_udf(F.col("src")) == True)
    & (check_ip_udf(F.col("dst")) == True)
)

dt4new1.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did that.
I'd like to remove the ones that don't have the correct names. I showed them in the second screenshot.
For example: "1.3" " ," .194.32.185 " ,  ".32.187", "0.4" etc

Comment: how are you determining which values are correct?